# PHP Amazon S3 upload WITH watermark

Tags: php

I current have a FULLY FUNCTIONING script that uploads pictures directly to my s3 bucket from my server...

However, I want to now start adding a watermark to every image that is uploaded.As you know upload to S3 never really stores it on the server, just as a temp file.

Basically, I am trying to upload an image to S3 (which works already) but before, I want to add a watermark to that image (not working).

HERE IS THE WORKING CODE THATS UPLOADS FILES TO MY S3 BUCKET:

```
        if (!class_exists('S3'))require_once('S3.php');

        //AWS access info
        if (!defined('awsAccessKey')) define('awsAccessKey', 'BLAHBLAH');
        if (!defined('awsSecretKey')) define('awsSecretKey', 'BLAHBLAH');

        //instantiate the class
        $s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);

        $fileName = $_FILES['theFile']['name'];
        $fileTempName = $_FILES['theFile']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['theFile']['size'];
        $fileExt = substr($fileName, strrpos($fileName, '.') + 1);
        $fileExt = strtolower($fileExt);

        $custompostid = rand(1000000,9999999);
        $imageName = $custompostid.".".$fileExt.""; 

        //move the file
        if ($s3->putObjectFile($fileTempName, "BUCKETNAME", $image, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ, array(), $imageType)) { 
        //success
        }
        else{   
        //error
        }
```

BUT BEFORE UPLOADING A FILE, I WANT TO ADD A WATERMARK TO EVERY IMAGE. WITH THIS FUNCTION:

```
        // getting the image name from GET variable
        $image = $_GET['image'];

        // creating png image of watermark
        $watermark = imagecreatefrompng('watermark.png');  

        // getting dimensions of watermark image
        $watermark_width = imagesx($watermark); 
        $watermark_height = imagesy($watermark); 

        // creting jpg from original image
        $image_path = '/path/to/image/folder/' . $image;
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path);
        //something went wrong
        if ($image === false) {
            return false;
        }
        // getting the dimensions of original image
        $size = getimagesize($image_path); 
        // placing the watermark 5px from bottom and right
        $dest_x = $size[0] - $watermark_width - 5; 
        $dest_y = $size[1] - $watermark_height - 5;
        // blending the images together
        imagealphablending($image, true);
        imagealphablending($watermark, true);
        // creating the new image
        imagecopy($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height);
        imagejpeg($image); 
        // destroying and freeing memory
        imagedestroy($image); 
        imagedestroy($watermark);
```

I want to combine these two working scripts into one. I'm sure its simple, all the code is here, I just don't know how to go about linking one process to the other. This is the best I can explain this.. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a question to answer, or at least a problem with the code you've written that you could describe?

Comment: Basically, I am trying to upload an image to S3 (which works already) but before, I want to add a watermark to that image (not working).

Comment: You'll need to be more specific on what is not working than "not working".

Comment: Okay, I separated the two blocks of code I want to put together (S3 PHOTO UPLOAD) & (ADD WATERMARK *BEFORE*). They work on their own, but not when I try to put them together, simply because I don't know how to link the temp photo file to the photo file which I want to watermark without causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

**S3 Image upload with Watermark Codeigniter**

```
                $s3_bucket_name = $this->config->item('s3_bucket_name');
                $s3_access_key = $this->config->item('s3_access_key');
                $s3_secret_key = $this->config->item('s3_secret_key');
                include('amazon/s3_config.php');
                $uploaddir = "images/";
                $actual_image_name = time().'.'.$ext;
                $newname=$uploaddir.$actual_image_name; 


                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'], $newname)) 
                {   
                    $this->watermarkimages($uploaddir,$actual_image_name);
                    $result_image='/'.$newname; 

                    if($s3->putObjectFile($newname, $bucket , $actual_image_name, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ) )
                    {
                        $s3file='http://'.$bucket.'.s3.amazonaws.com/'.$actual_image_name;
                        mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos(product_image,product_id) VALUES('$s3file','$prd_id')");
                    } 
                    unlink($newname);
                }
```

public function watermarkimages($uploaddir,$image_name)
{

```
        $masterURL =$uploaddir.$image_name;


        $path='images/watermark3.png';


                $this->load->library('image_lib');              
                $config1['image_library'] = 'gd2'; 
                $config1['source_image']     = $masterURL;
                $config1['wm_type']          = 'overlay';
                $config1['wm_overlay_path']  = $path; 
                $config1['wm_opacity']       = 100;
                $config1['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'top';
                $config1['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'right';
                $this->image_lib->initialize($config1);
                $this->image_lib->watermark();



}
```